# Is there a clearer name to describe the Array Syntax in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I can read in AngularJS doc that when using a syntax where dependencies are specified in strings before being used in function. (e.g. `.controller('InvoiceController', ['currencyConverter', function(currencyConverter) { [...]`), this is called *Array Syntax*.

> Angular uses this array syntax to define the dependencies so that the DI also works after minifying the code, which will most probably rename the argument name of the controller constructor function to something shorter like a.

I'm searching for a clearer, or at least more specialized term to describe this approach, as I think that it sounds weird and means nothing when discuting with co-workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is called 'Inline Array Annotation', it is a type of 'Dependency Annotation'.

You are basically annotating the controller so that the injector knows what services to inject into the function.

There are three ways of annotating your code with service name information:

- Using the inline array annotation (this is the preferred approach).
- Using the $inject property annotation.
- Implicitly from the function parameter names (not recommended).

Taken from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

**Inline Array Annotation**

> What you have in your example. You specify the dependencies in an
>   in-line array.

```
myModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'someService', function($scope, someService ... ]
```

---

**$inject Property Annotation**

> Here you can use `$inject` to inject your dependencies.

```
var MyController = function($scope, someService) ...

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'someService'];
myApp.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

---

**Implicit Annotation**

> Here you don't specify the dependencies in an array. This causes
>   problems if you minify your code.

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, someService)
```

---

Answer (score 2):

The Angular docs specify three terms for injection annotation:

- Inference
- $inject Annotation
- Inline (this is the array syntax to which your question refers)

Perhaps that's the term you're looking for.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Answer (score 0):

Basicly what happens is that using Array Syntax instead of just parameters in the function, you make sure that the dependencies are injected exactly as defined in the array syntax. If you would not use the array syntax, there is a chance that the minification of your code renames the dependencies of your controller to a, b, c and your app would not know what you want to inject with a, b, c. While when you use the Array Syntax, your app knows that a stands for the first entry in your array, b for the second, c for the third etc. In other words, It doesn't matter how the dependencies inside the: function() bit are called, as long as the names in the array match the names of the dependencies you want to inject.

Answer (score 0):

This parameter of controller is in an array format, hence the array syntax term. I think what you actually need to communicate is that controller takes as parameter a *dependency list in an array format*.

Comment: That's exactly what is not clear. There is a concept of reflectivity with this array syntax, and just describing it as a dependency list doesn't make justice to this concept.